# How to show array data in page using angularJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework

i want show array data in view page using angularjs and ionic.

Here is my category controller output array format:

```
["Mouse", "Keyboard"]
```

Here is view code:

```
<span ng-repeat="cat in category track by $index">
   <ion-item ui-sref="home.add" href="#">
      <h2 class="list-text">{{cat.data}}</h2>
   </ion-item>
</span>
```

Please help me to find out the problem.

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this

```
<span ng-repeat="cat in category track by $index">
   <ion-item ui-sref="home.add" href="#">
      <h2 class="list-text">{{cat}}</h2>
   </ion-item>
</span>
```